# PHP Object Indices as Strings?

Tags: php, arrays, string, object

Is there a way to access a member of an object, by using its name as a string?

When I declare an array...

```
$array = array();
$array['description_en']="hello";
$array['description_fr']="bonjour";
```

then I access a member like this:

```
$lang="en"; //just to show my purpose. it will be dynamic
$description = $array['description_'.$lang];
```

Can I do the same thing for objects?

For example:

```
$obj->description_en="hello";
$obj->description_fr="bonjour";
```

How can I access `$obj->description_.$lang` ?

Comment: `$obj->{"description_".$lang}` or `$objRef = "description_".$lang; $obj->$objRef`

Comment: @MarkBaker Can I ask why that's a comment instead of an answer? That's worth of being posted as a full answer isn't it?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - mainly because I don't consider it worthy of answering if I can post a response in fewer characters than the limit of a tweet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class test
{
    public $description_en = 'english';
}

$obj = new test();
$lang = 'en';
echo $obj->{"description_".$lang}; // echo's "english"
```

You can see more examples of variable variables [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Thank you ! and all the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    public $varA = 11;
    public $varB = 22;
    public $varC = 33;
}

$myObj = new MyClass();

echo $myObj->{"varA"} . "<br>";
echo $myObj->{"varB"} . "<br>";
echo $myObj->{"varC"} . "<br>";
```

This way, you can access object variables as if they were entries in an associative array.